# "use client" breaks Next.js Image tag

Tags: javascript, next.js, nextjs-image

My program works fine until I add the "use client" directive on feed.tsx. I want to change the behavior of scrolling in the Feed component, so I need to specify that it should be rendered client-side. However, this makes the page crash. If I temporarily remove the Image tag inside of cell.tsx, the program works again.

Here's my code:

cell.tsx

```
import tempImg from "../../public/assets/image.png"
import Image from "next/image"

export default function Cell() {
  return (
    <>
      <div>Username</div>
      <Image src={tempImg} alt="temp img"/>
    </>
  );
}
```

feed.tsx

```
"use client";
import Cell from "./cell";

export default function Feed({numCells}) {
  const handleScroll = (e: any) => {
    console.log("scrolling")
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div onScroll={e => handleScroll(e)}>
        {Array.from({ length: numCells }, (_, index) => (
          <Cell key={index}/>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

The error I'm receiving is:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: __webpack_require__.n is not a function. (In '__webpack_require__.n(next_image__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__)', '__webpack_require__.n' is undefined)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You cannot import Server component directly into client component. Please, refer to the nextjs documentation: [Unsupported Pattern: Importing Server Components into Client Components](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#unsupported-pattern-importing-server-components-into-client-components).

Pass it as a child instead, as the above article recommends, or simply add the `use client` directive to both components.

Comment: Adding "use client" to both components results in the same error, I'm trying to think of a way to pass it as a child but I don't think that'll work with the structure I'm envisioning.

Comment: I wonder why don't you get an error for missing image widht and height attibutes btw.

Comment: @gazdergo you don't need to specify width and height if you're using a static image